# ASP.NET 4.0 Error handling doesn't works except 500 status

Tags: c#-4.0, error-handling, webforms

I specified custom error in my project

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="http://redirect" />
```

It works on 500 error status , but It doesn't works when I made another errors
Like http://127.0.0.1/home/1 for testing of 403 or 404 error is well handled .

It doesn't work . My IIS server returned to IIS default error page of 403 or 404 How can I handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
    <error code="403" path="403.html" />
    <error code="404" path="404.html" />
    <error code="500" path="500.html" />
</customErrors>
```

For more details read at MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx)